# Inverted border radius with complex box shadow

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to recreate this print card that has a inverse border radius and a couple borders.  I got the borders working on a rectangle using box shadow, and I am fudging the inverted corners with 100% border radius divs.  I applied the shadow to the rounded corners though and it looks super off.

Is there any way to use circle svgs to clip the corners then use filter: drop-shadow?  not sure that's possible.  any better ideas?

html:

```
   #greetings
    .top.left
    .top.right
    .bottom.left
    .bottom.right
```

css:

```
#greetings{
  box-shadow:  -6px 6px 0 #8E9090, 6px -6px 0 #8E9090, -6px -6px 0 #8E9090, 6px 6px 0 #8E9090, -9px 9px 0 #f88125, 9px -9px 0 #f88125,9px 9px 0 #f88125, -9px -9px 0 #f88125, -12px 12px 0 #8E9090, 12px -12px 0 #8E9090, 12px 12px 0 #8E9090, -12px -12px 0 #8E9090;;

  div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #f88125;
  }

  .top { top: -20px; }
  .bottom { bottom: -20px; }
  .left { left: -20px; }
  .right { right: -20px; }

  .top.right {
    box-shadow:  -6px 6px 0 #8E9090,  -9px 9px 0 #f88125,  -12px 12px 0 #8E9090;
  }
```

Target:[image]

Html corners:[image]

Wonky shadow: [image]

Comment: Could you include the html and css?

Comment: Why not just do the **whole** thing as an SVG?

Comment: it needs to expand depending on the dynamic text inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't pull this off with your box-shadow approach.

I achieved something similar with borders and relative positioning. Didn't have time to polish the code, and if you look closely it is not symmetrical. It is not finished, but I thought I'd collaborate with an alternative.

I'm sure you can play around with the circles div widths to make the card look more similar to the original.

[image]

html

```
<div class="label">
        <div class="inner-border-two"></div>
        <div class="inner-border"></div>
        <div class="corner-0 corner"></div>
        <div class="corner-0 inner corner"></div>
        <div class="border border-top"></div>
        <div class="corner-1 corner"></div>
        <div class="corner-1 inner corner"></div>
        <div class="border border-right"></div>
        <div class="corner-2 corner"></div>
        <div class="corner-2 inner corner"></div>
        <div class="border border-bottom"></div>
        <div class="corner-3 corner"></div>
        <div class="corner-3 inner corner"></div>
        <div class="border border-left"></div>
    </div>
```

css

```
.label{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 660px;
  height: 458px;
  border: 30px solid #F88125;
  padding: 0;
}

.label .inner-border-two{
  height: 104%;
  width: 103%;
  border: 2px solid #8E9090;
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: -8px;
}

.label .inner-border{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 6px solid #8E9090;
  position: absolute;
}


.label .corner {
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #F88125; //Orange
}

.label .corner-0{
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #8E9090;
  border-right: 6px solid #8E9090;
}

.label .corner-0.inner{
  left: -8px;
  top: -8px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #8E9090;
  border-right: 3px solid #8E9090;
}

.label .corner-1{
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #8E9090;
  border-left: 6px solid #8E9090;
}

.label .corner-1.inner{
  right: -10px;
  top: -8px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #8E9090;
  border-left: 3px solid #8E9090;
}

.label .corner-2{
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  border-top: 6px solid #8E9090;
  border-left: 6px solid #8E9090;
}

.label .corner-2.inner{
  right: -10px;
  bottom: -8px;
  border-top: 3px solid #8E9090;
  border-left: 3px solid #8E9090;
}

.label .corner-3{
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  border-top: 6px solid #8E9090;
  border-right: 6px solid #8E9090;
}

.label .corner-3.inner{
  left: -8px;
  bottom: -8px;
  border-top: 3px solid #8E9090;
  border-right: 3px solid #8E9090;
}
```